# Задать Visual для VisualBrush в виде {StaticResource .}

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно менять векторные изображения на холсте, векторы буду брать из :

```
**Код XML**

<Application.Resources>        
            <Viewbox x:Key="VectorImage">
            <Canvas>
                <Path .......>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox x:Key="VectorImage2">
            <Canvas >
                <Ellipse .....>                   
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Проблема собственно в том что не могу задать в C# параметр для Visual. Подскажите как правильно сделать.

```
**Код C#**

VisualBrush brush = new VisualBrush(Canvas1);
brush.Visual =?????????? // тут должно быть {StaticResource VectorImage}, но не могу понять как это выглядит на шарпе.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы вам не класть в ресурсы сам `VisualBrush`? Весь геморрой отпадёт, включая вообще необходимость что-то делать вручную на C#. Заодно должна уйти проблема использования одного и того же UI-элемента во многих местах.

Вообще, в WPF ручное создание контролов на C# — моветон, так никто не делает, всё (ну, почти всё) можно выразить через XAML.

Если хочется помучиться, в [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx) есть пример.

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал. Я не так давно перешел на WPF, видно нужно действительно более детально изучать XAML.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Удачи вам!

WPF, когда вы к нему привыкнете, будет намного удобнее.